How can I use my own strategy to test by backtrader?
I try to backtest my strategy of trading that is named "AI reversal". Light-weight implementation is available in strategies and I checked the document of backtrader to be right. But everytime I run it, it's just showing the data and not my buy or sell or any of portfolio overtime and ...
My implementation should get the last 24 hours data as 15 minutes timeframes for each point of chart and then decide to buy or sell.
import backtrader as bt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import empyrical as ep
from datetime import datetime
from ai_reversal import (
    prepare_dataz,
    feature_engineering,
    tune_model,
    train_and_evaluate_model,
    run_ai_reversal
)
import warnings
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="ta.trend")

# Custom Analyzer for tracking performance and portfolio value
class PerformanceAnalyzer(bt.Analyzer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.portfolio_values = []
        self.pnl = []

    def notify_trade(self, trade):
        if trade.isclosed:
            self.pnl.append(trade.pnl)

    def next(self):
        # Track portfolio value at each step
        self.portfolio_values.append(self.strategy.broker.get_value())

    def get_analysis(self):
        return {
            'cumulative_pnl': sum(self.pnl),
            'average_pnl': np.mean(self.pnl) if self.pnl else 0,
            'max_pnl': max(self.pnl) if self.pnl else 0,
            'min_pnl': min(self.pnl) if self.pnl else 0,
            'portfolio_values': self.portfolio_values
        }

# Define a custom indicator to track the target value for the AI strategy
class TargetIndicator(bt.Indicator):
    lines = ('target',)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def next(self):
        # Target value for upward trend (1) or downward (0)
        if self.data.close[0] > self.data.close[-1]:
            self.lines.target[0] = 1
        else:
            self.lines.target[0] = 0

# AI Reversal Strategy
class AIReversalStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    params = (
        ('symbol', 'BTCUSD'),
        ('interval', 5),  # Interval in minutes
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.signals = None
        self.order = None
        self.buy_signal = None
        self.sell_signal = None
        self.buy_signals = []
        self.sell_signals = []

        # Initialize buy/sell signal prices to track executed prices
        self.buy_signal_price = None
        self.sell_signal_price = None

        # Technical indicators
        self.rsi = bt.indicators.RSI(self.data.close, period=14)
        self.sma_10 = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data.close, period=10)
        self.sma_30 = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data.close, period=30)
        self.stoch_k = bt.indicators.StochasticSlow(self.data)
        self.macd = bt.indicators.MACD(self.data.close)

        # Custom target indicator (up/down trend)
        self.target = TargetIndicator(self.data)

        # Variables for machine learning
        self.model = None
        self.signals = None

    def next(self):
        current_time = datetime.now()
        if current_time.weekday() >= 5:  # Skip weekends
            return

        if current_time.minute % self.params.interval == 0:
            self.data_raw = self.get_data()
            if not self.data_raw.empty:
                self.signals = self.run_ai_reversal_pipeline(self.data_raw)
                self.execute_orders()

        # Display target value
        print(f"Target: {self.target.target[0]}")

        # AI prediction logic
        if self.model is not None:
            features = self.prepare_features()
            prediction = self.model.predict([features])
            signal = 'Buy' if prediction == 1 else 'Sell'
            print(f"AI Prediction: {signal}")

            # Buy Signal
            if signal == 'Buy' and not self.position:  # Buy only if no current position
                print("Generating Buy signal...")
                self.buy_signal_price = self.data.close[0]
                self.order = self.buy()  # Execute buy order
                print(f"Buy signal executed at price: {self.buy_signal_price}")
                self.buy_signals.append((self.data.datetime.datetime(), self.data.close[0]))

            # Sell Signal
            elif signal == 'Sell' and self.position:  # Sell only if currently holding a position
                print("Generating Sell signal...")
                self.sell_signal_price = self.data.close[0]
                self.order = self.sell()  # Execute sell order
                print(f"Sell signal executed at price: {self.sell_signal_price}")
                self.sell_signals.append((self.data.datetime.datetime(), self.data.close[0]))

    def prepare_features(self):
        # Convert Backtrader LineBuffer objects to Pandas Series for ML model prediction
        close_series = pd.Series(self.data.close.get(size=len(self.data)), index=self.data.datetime.get(size=len(self.data)))
        rsi_series = pd.Series(self.rsi.get(size=len(self.rsi)), index=self.data.datetime.get(size=len(self.rsi)))
        sma_10_series = pd.Series(self.sma_10.get(size=len(self.sma_10)), index=self.data.datetime.get(size=len(self.sma_10)))
        sma_30_series = pd.Series(self.sma_30.get(size=len(self.sma_30)), index=self.data.datetime.get(size=len(self.sma_30)))
        stoch_k_series = pd.Series(self.stoch_k.get(size=len(self.stoch_k)), index=self.data.datetime.get(size=len(self.stoch_k)))
        macd_series = pd.Series(self.macd.get(size=len(self.macd)), index=self.data.datetime.get(size(len(self.macd))))

        # Prepare feature vector (ignoring NA values)
        features = pd.DataFrame({
            'rsi': rsi_series,
            'sma_10': sma_10_series,
            'sma_30': sma_30_series,
            'stoch_k': stoch_k_series,
            'macd': macd_series
        }).dropna().iloc[-1].values  # Get the most recent row for prediction

        return features

    def run_ai_reversal_pipeline(self, data):
        if len(data) == 0:
            print("Error: DataFrame is empty. Skipping AI reversal pipeline.")
            return None

        print("Running AI reversal pipeline...")
        prepared_data = self.prepare_data(data)

        features, target = self.feature_engineering(prepared_data)
        model = self.train_and_evaluate_model(features, target)
        self.model = model
        print("Model training completed.")

        return prepared_data

    def prepare_data(self, data):
        close_series = pd.Series(data.close.get(size=len(data)), index=data.datetime.get(size(len(data))))
        data['target'] = np.where(close_series.shift(-1) > close_series, 1, 0)
        return data.dropna()

    def feature_engineering(self, data):
        features = data[['rsi', 'sma_10', 'sma_30', 'stoch_k', 'macd']]
        target = data['target']
        return features, target

    def tune_model(self, features, target):
        param_grid = {
            'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],
            'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
            'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4]
        }
        rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
        grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
        grid_search.fit(features, target)
        return grid_search.best_estimator_

    def train_and_evaluate_model(self, features, target):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
        model = self.tune_model(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
        print(f'Model Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100:.2f}%')
        return model

    def notify_order(self, order):
        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            if order.isbuy():
                print(f"BUY EXECUTED: Price = {order.executed.price}, Size = {order.executed.size}")
            elif order.issell():
                print(f"SELL EXECUTED: Price = {order.executed.price}, Size = {order.executed.size}")
            self.order = None  # Reset the order variable

        elif order.status in [order.Canceled, order.Margin, order.Rejected]:
            print("Order Canceled/Margin/Rejected")
            self.order = None  # Reset the order variable

    def notify_trade(self, trade):
        if trade.isclosed:
            print(f"TRADE CLOSED: Gross PnL = {trade.pnl:.2f}, Net PnL = {trade.pnlcomm:.2f}")

# Initialize Cerebro engine
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

# Add strategy to Cerebro
cerebro.addstrategy(AIReversalStrategy)

# Load Data (example CSV file with timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume columns)
data = pd.read_csv('historical_data.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
data.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
datafeed = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=data)
cerebro.adddata(datafeed)

# Configure the broker settings
cerebro.broker.set_cash(1000)
cerebro.broker.setcommission(commission=0.001)

# Add analyzers to evaluate strategy performance
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.SharpeRatio, _name='sharpe_ratio')
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.DrawDown, _name='drawdown')
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.TradeAnalyzer, _name='trade_analyzer')

# Add observers to plot buy/sell signals and portfolio changes
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.BuySell)
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.Broker)

# Run the strategy
results = cerebro.run()
final_value = cerebro.broker.get_value()
print(f"Final Portfolio Value: {final_value}")

# Plot the results (including buy/sell signals and portfolio changes)
cerebro.plot(style='candlestick')


What exactly did you see as output, and what exactly did you expect to see instead, and what exactly have you tried to debug your program? As it stands this is just a code dump and the statement that "it didn't work"

After taking a quick look at your code I found at least two possible causes of your issues.

you want to trade BTCUSD but you set your capital to $1000. As you did not show a sample of the data you used, it might be possible that your strategy tries to buy btc but it cant because your account has not enough cash. Set your cash to higher amount and try again.
this part of your function is not doing what you expect. :

def next(self):
    current_time = datetime.now()
    if current_time.weekday() >= 5:  # Skip weekends
        return

the datetime.now() function gives you the actual current date  not the current date in your backtest. If you run your backtest on a weekend it will not even attempt to buy anything.
We could give you a better answer if you would have included a data sample and a sample log of your program. Maybe another look at documentation could help. DateTime Management
